# Adding text to php generated barcode image

Tags: php, image

I currently am using a script I have found online to generate barcodes for my company. I have modified it a bit to allow the barcode to expand horizontally. The only thing I am lacking is the text the barcode is generating.

I would like the text centered underneath the barcode in a justifiable font size to the barcode.

Here is my barcode script http://pastebin.com/wvTyxQrW

To generate you just go to barcode.php?text=1o2020p1 for example. I just wanted to have that text in the image below the barcode centered. I am just not proefficient enough with image manipulation to do this, it would take me hours.

Thank you for your suggestions / help!

Comment: You can use `imagettftext()`.

Comment: use [`imagestring`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) or [`imagefttext`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
  $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
```

with

```
  $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + 20);
```

And add the following code above `// Draw barcode to the screen`

```
if (!empty($_GET['text'])) {
  imagestring($image, 5, 4, $img_height, $_GET['text'], $black);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! IS there a way for me to center the text horizontally with the length of the barcode?

Comment: I was able to sort something out and get it centered. Here is the code I used:
 `$font = 5;
 $font_width = ImageFontWidth($font);
 $font_height = ImageFontHeight($font);

 $text_width = $font_width * strlen($text);

 // Position to align in center
 $position_center = ceil(($img_width - $text_width) / 2);`

Comment: that seems to be a perfect solution.